# When Tor starts Glib Critical message - what is it?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

(process:4137): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed

ubuntu 14.04.1 trusty

What does the message mean?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a [Firefox bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=672671), nothing specific to Tor Browser.